# pass value inside ng-repeat as string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have directive with ng-repeat, and would like to pass value to iterate through from outside.

like

```
<mydirective list="array" repeatstring="item in list | firstfilter | secondfilter |orderBy:value"></mydirective>
<mydirective list="array"  repeatstring="item in list | thirdfilter | secondfilter |orderBy:value"></mydirective>
<mydirective list="array"  repeatstring="item in list | fourthfilter | secondfilter |orderBy:value"></mydirective>
```

and the directive to look like

```
  <div ng-repeat="{{repeatstring}}">
<!--repeat insides -->
</div>
```

I've tried different variants with different binding and ng-init, but the only results it seams to show is eather expression errors or non-rendered ng-repeat.
Maybe someone has pulled this trick with angular

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q37gC/2/

Comment: could you please add your directive code?

Comment: what is your `{{repeatstring}}` ???

Comment: it is value passed from the outerscope, string, smth like
item in list | fourthfilter | secondfilter |orderBy:value

Comment: @PankajParkar fiddled example http://jsfiddle.net/Q37gC/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid **you can't** ! [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971271/angular-ng-repeat-expressions-as-variables)

So skip custom directive and use [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters) with `ng-repeat` like

```
ng-repeat="item in list | myFilter"

myApp.filter('myFilter', function () {
    return function (input) {
        // use your logic
    };
});
```

Comment: not an option :) but thank you for pointing me in the direction of another answer