# Is there a way to bind the repeat_expression of ngRepeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am wondering whether I can set the repeat_expression in the scope and bind it in HTML?
Such as:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="expression">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat={{expression}}>{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.expression = "item in items";
```

Comment: I guess you can not do this.! but what error you are getting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971271/angular-ng-repeat-expressions-as-variables